# Maven plugins binding when no execution details is specified in POM

Tags: maven

When no execution details is specified for a plugin in the POM file, then is there a default phase of the maven lifecycle to which the plugin is bind to?

I assume the plugin could only be called explicitly via the command line in this scenario.

Comment: It depends. Which plugin are we talking about? Plugins are not forced to bind to a default phase.

Comment: @Tunaki: For example, I see the maven release plugin in Maven super pom without any execution detail. Which phase is this binded to. Does it depend on the plugin we are using?
<plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>

Comment: There's a difference between default phase and no execution detail. In the Super POM, the plugins are there to fix a specific version for that plugin (it serves as a default when you don't specify the version for that plugin). It has nothing to do with default phase. For example, the `maven-release-plugin` is not bound to a default phase: to invoke it, you call it via the command line or you need to add an execution with an appropriate phase.

Comment: Clear. If execution tag is not mentioned for the plugin in POM file then the plugin is not binded to any phase of the lifecycle and can only be called explicitly through command line

Comment: Not always, a plugin can be bound to a default phase. For example [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) compile goal is bound to the compile phase by default. So even if there's no executions section, it will be executed on the compile phase.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of plugins depends on the phase (life cycle) you're calling and the artifact type you're producing e.g. when your project produces a pom (`<packaging>pom</packaging>`) instead of a jar (jar or no `<packaging>` element specified), the compile plugin is not called at all.

For a list of executed goals (plugins) see
[the complete Maven reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html#lifecycle-sect-jar).

If you want to check what plugins are configured for your project, check the effective pom which can be created by calling

`mvn help:effective-pom`

The effective pom is a merge of the super pom and your project's pom.

[see this tutorial for an example of an effective pom](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_pom.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are different things. First the [life cycle which defines executions of particular plugins](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html).

Apart from that a plugin can define a default life cycle phase where it will be executed which is defined by the plugin author.

For example the [xml-maven-plugin binds to the generate-resources](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/transform-mojo.html) phase. Excerpt from the docs:

> Requires a Maven project to be executed. 
>   Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: generate-resources.

Here the plugin binds by default to the `generate-resources` life cycle phase. Or you can look at the [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html) and many other plugins.

Of course you can call a plugin via command line if the appropriate plugin supports that. Otherwise you can bind the plugin via execution block to a particular life cycle phase.